# Check if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)}{n}$is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Check if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)}{n}$is convergent. 
I have elaborated on this question for a while and I have come up with an answer - yes, it is convergent. First, let's say that $$a_n= \frac{1}{n}$$ We can infer that $\lim a_n = 0$ and that $a_1 >a_2 > a_3> \dots$ 
Now, consider $$b_n = \sin(n)$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} sin(n)$$ is clearly bounded, although I don't know how to prove it. (Any suggestions would be most welcome).  
And so my reasoning has reached the seminal point - by virtue of Abel theorem - the series in question is clearly bounded. Is it correct?

Comment: How did you get that the last summation is 'clearly' bounded?

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra, could you add a little bit more information to your comment?

Comment: @copper.hat, 
I cheated a little bit and I graphed it for several thousand terms.

Comment: That hardly constitutes 'clearly'.

Comment: Hint: $\sin n = \frac{1}{2i} (e^{in} - e^{-in})$.  Now, calculate the partial sum using the geometric series partial sum formula.